# SQL запрос. Как посчитать кол-во записей в месяц понедельно

Tags: php, sql, запрос

**Дано.** Есть таблица *info_yarluk* и в ней присутствует столбец по которому делаем выборки - *info_date_start* (формат дата). 
**Задача.** Сделать подсчет кол-ва записей за месяц и сгрупировать понедельно.

Пришел к такому запросу:

> $info_year = date('Y'); 
>  $info_month = date('n');
>
> $sql = "SELECT info_date_start, count(info_date_start),
>   WEEK(info_date_start)  FROM info_yarluk WHERE MONTH(info_date_start) =
>   $info_month AND YEAR(info_date_start) = $info_year GROUP BY
>   WEEK(info_date_start)";

Выдает массив:

```
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  int(0)
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2016-04-22"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2016-04-01"
  [4]=>
  int(0)
  [8]=>
  string(10) "2016-04-12"
}
```

Как правильно составить запрос?

Comment: запрос кроме некоторых недочетов не сильно влияющих на результат уже должен получать то что требуется. а вот откуда у вас в php берется представленный массив, совершенно не соответствующий приведенному запросу - ума не приложу. видимо что то намудрено в php коде который этот массив сделал

Comment: возможно проблема в именах полей. добавьте alias'ы всем вычислимым полям. Хотя, конечно, структура массива очень странна

Comment: Про не понятки с массивом откуда он берется: предположил что весь код выкладывать не имеет смысла, хотя сейчас понимаю что это помогло бы решить задачу. Потому как ваш комментарий касательно того что что-то намудрено в php помогло найти проблему.

Comment: Прикрепил решение ниже

Answer (score 2):

У вас же два вопроса в одном? верно?!

Первый, кол-во записей за месяц

а второй, сгруппировать записи по неделям. Хотя не понятно, что сначит сгруппировать в данном задании. Будем считать, что получить кол-во по неделям.
Если да, то и решать надо 2 запросами

1) кол-во записей по месяцам

```
 SELECT MONTH(info_date_start) , YEAR(info_date_start), count(info_date_start) FROM info_yarluk 
GROUP BY MONTH(info_date_start) , YEAR(info_date_start);
```

2) сгруппировать данные по неделям.

```
 SELECT MONTH(info_date_start) , YEAR(info_date_start), WEEK(info_date_start), count(info_date_start) FROM info_yarluk 
GROUP BY MONTH(info_date_start) , YEAR(info_date_start),WEEK(info_date_start);
```

Comment: нет, автор хочет выбрать записи за определенный месяц и сгруппировать по неделям. ваш ответ на другой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Решение лежало в области php. Выкладываю весь кусок кода с решением.

```
$info_year = date('Y'); // по умолчанию ГОД текущий 
$info_month = date('n'); // по умолчанию МЕСЯЦ текущий

$sql = "SELECT
          info_date_start,
          count(info_date_start),
          WEEK(info_date_start)
        FROM
          info_yarluk
        WHERE
          MONTH(info_date_start) = $info_month
        AND
          YEAR(info_date_start) = $info_year
        GROUP BY
          WEEK(info_date_start)";

$result = $connect->query($sql);

while ($count = $result->fetch_array()) {   
  $week_arr[] = $count[1]; 
}
```

Смотрю что получили в массиве:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Все верно. Ручной подсчет записей показал что цифры верные.
 
Спасибо пользователю Mike, что натолкнули на путь к решению.